# Serving Pyramid App with UWSGI and NGINX

Tags: nginx, pyramid, reverse-proxy, uwsgi

I am new to NGINX, uWSGI AND Pyramid, and I am trying to serve a Pyramid app through uWSGI using nginx as a reverse proxy. I am really stuck at the moment and am hoping someone can make some suggestions for how to solve this. If you can explain a little what might be going on, that would be helpful too, as my understanding is very limited!

Currently, I am getting an `Internal Server Error' from uWSGI when I visit the reverse proxy URL. In the uWSGI error log, I am getting the error:

```
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
```

The application works fine when I serve through uWSGI alone, launching with pserve. I can launch it from my virtual envelope as follows:

```
bin/pserve my-app/uwsgi.ini
```

But when I start nginx, and visit the proxy address, I get the Internal Server Error.

The settings I have in uwsgi.ini are as follows:

```
[app:main]
use = egg:myapp
pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en
pyramid_debugtoolbar
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543

[loggers]
keys = root, musiccircle

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = ERROR
handlers = console
[logger_musiccircle]
level = ERROR
handlers =
qualname = musiccircle

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s

[uwsgi]
socket = unix://home/usr/env/myapp/myapp.sock
master = true

processes = 48
cpu-affinity = 12

harakiri = 60
post-buffering = 8192
buffer-size = 65535

daemonize = ./uwsgi.log
pidfile = ./pid_5000.pid

listen = 32767

reload-on-as = 512
reload-on-rss = 192
limit-as = 1024
no-orphans = true
reload-mercy = 8
log-slow = true

virtualenv = /home/usr/env
```

And in the corresponding myapp.conf file in nginx, I have the following:

```
upstream myapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:6543;
}

server {
    listen          8080;
    server_name myapp.local www.myapp.local;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/usr/env/myapp;
    }
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    charset         utf-8;
    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix://home/usr/env/myapp/myapp.sock;
    }
}
```

If you need to see anything else, please let me know. As you can see, Nginx is configured to serve at port 8080 (which it does), and the Pyramid app is being served by uWSGI to port 6543 (which it does).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your configuration file is for Pyramid `pserve` not for `uwsgi` as far as I can see.

Comment: In your nginx.conf, try chaning server 127.0.0.1:6543 to server 0.0.0.0:6543

Comment: In your Nginx file the uwsgi_pass directive should be  uwsgi_pass      unix:///home/usr/env/myapp/myapp.sock; (3 slashes).
In your uwsgi.ini file coment out these lines use = egg:waitress#main,host = 0.0.0.0,port = 6543. In your [uwsgi] section you don't have to add unix:// when specifying a socket path. Another thing that did it for me was to add the proper permissions for the socket. Here's my config for my wsgi section http://pastebin.com/PB89jGMM. I start it with env/bin/uwsgi --ini-paste uwsgi.ini

Comment: Mikko Ohtamaa, you were right...I was serving my app through paster/pserve with waitress, not uwsgi as intended. I therefore decided, why not just modify my nginx conf, and continue to serve with waitress? This is what I did, and crooksey, thanks, you were right, I needed to modify my .ini file so that the 2 host IPs matched. It is now working with the waitress + nginx configuration, although I have issues accessing the site in Chrome (that's another issue though!). webjunkie, thanks for your suggestions, I will try this option out too.

Comment: Yeah I think it is possible to run Nginx + pserve, though most people seem to prefer uwsgi.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Pyramid projects are intended to be *installed* (`setup.py`) and then run with a `.ini` configuration file with `pserve`.  Pserve then passes in these config file details as `**settings` to your Pyramid app at run time.

This is different than, say, Flask which is *not installed* and generally has *no* configuration file.  Such a Flask application can be run by uWSGI as needed, with all run-time configuration being handled by uWSGI or environment variables.

Since Pyramid usually needs a config file at run time, and relies on pserve to provide them when using a config file (ie `production.ini`), I think you'll have to run `uwsgi --ini-paste production.ini` (or if running with Pypy, `uwsgi --pypy-paste production.ini`) (thanks to @Sorrel)